# Expand disk space of a Windows 10 S.O. disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, clonezilla

I clone a 128GB disk to 256GB disk with clonezilla using disk to disk copy. The new disk works but I cannot expand volumes because the disk is recognized by OS as 128GB disk. How can use the other half disk?

Comment: For sure using the new bigger drive, removed the smaller one? If the OS is only looking at the old smaller drive it would say the same thing... Or can you create new partitions on the bigger drive?

Comment: Using Gparted on Ubuntu live CD I see the unallocated space, in Windows Disk format tool I cannot see any space and moreover the entire disk is recognized with the old size.

Comment: I tried to expand the ntfs partitiom with GParted but Windows still recognize its volume with the old size.

Comment: @Tobia I'd advise you to repeat the cloning procedure using the same or, better yet, a different cloning software. I believe this would be a lot easier for you to execute, instead of trying to get that partition to show up. I'd also suggest you to reformat the SSD using the tools that can actually see the correct size of the drive and then begin again. Good luck!

Comment: Very strange... how about just expand the volume with gparted? Or create a new partition? Or try different partition tools for windows? I'm reluctant to write all the data again yet, ssd's do have a finite write life, and it may just do the same thing.

Comment: I found the solution... I had to use again clonezilla because I don't know any other software for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run clonezilla again coping disk to disk in expert mode and setting **-k1** option to proportionally resize the destination partition table.
It works!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a livecd and a tool like gparted to increase the partition size to full disk size

Comment: I tried it. Please see my comment of the question.

Comment: Great! you might want to close the question =)

Comment: I have to wait 8hr :-)